# Make use of the relation name/table name/file name in Hadoop's MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to use the relation name in MapReduce's Map and Reduce? I am trying to do Set difference using Hadoop's MapReduce.

**Input:** 2 files R and S containing list of terms. (Am going to use t to denote a term)

**Objective:** To find R - S, i.e. terms in R and not in S

**Approach:**

Mapper: Spits out t -> R or t -> S, depending on whether t comes from R or S. So, the map output has the t as the key and the file name as the value.

Reducer: If the value list for a t contains only R, then output t -> t.

Do I need to some how tag the terms with the filename? Or is there any other way?

Source code for something I did for Set Union (doesn't need file name anywhere in this case). Just wanted to use this as an example to illustrate the unavailability of filename in Mapper.

```
public class Union {
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

                public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                        output.collect(value, value);
                }
        }

        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

                public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
                        while (values.hasNext())
                        {
                                output.collect(key, values.next());
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                JobConf conf = new JobConf(Union.class);
                conf.setJobName("Union");
                conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

                conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
                conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
                conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
                conf.set("mapred.job.queue.name", "myQueue");
                conf.setNumReduceTasks(5);

                conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
                conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

                JobClient.runJob(conf);
        }
}
```

As you can see I can't identify which key -> value pair (input to the Mapper) came from which file. Am I overlooking something simple here?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement your question just like you answered. That is just the way MapReduce was meant to be.
I guess your problem was actually writing n-times the same value into the HDFS?
**EDIT:**
*Pasted from my Comment down there*

Ah I got it ;) I'm not really familiar with the "old" API, but you can "query" your Reporter with:

```
reporter.getInputSplit();
```

This returns you an interface called InputSplit. This is easily castable to "FileSplit". And within FileSplit object you could obtain the Path with: "split.getPath()". And from the Path object you just need to call the getName() method.

So this snippet should work for you:

```
FileSplit fsplit = reporter.getInputSplit(); // maybe cast it down to FileSplit if needed..
String yourFileName = fsplit.getPath().getName();
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have updated my question my a code snippet. I hope it clarifies my question. I am more concerned about how to get the file name within the mapper.

Comment: Ah I got it ;) I'm not really familiar with the "old" API, but you can query your Reporter with: reporter.getInputSplit(). This return you an Interface called InputSplit. This is easily castable to "FileSplit". And within FileSplit object you could obtain the Path with: "split.getPath()". And from the Path object you just need to call the getName() method.

Comment: NP :) Glad I've helped you ;)